# How can i list only applications excluding widgets and services in a grid view in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am able to List all applications using code mentioned on [that page](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/).

I want to filter it and just list the applications installed in the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You have your concepts a bit wrong.

Widgets and services are part of an application, just like the activities are.
Some activities are meant to show in the launcher, that's when you declare them on the manifest with the intent-filter MAIN and DEFAULT.

What you probably want is to get the activities that declare such intent filters.
And how to do it is in the Utilities class of you the link you provided.